# Google's Scala performance benchmarks

Tags: java, scala, benchmarking

Last year google published a benchmark comparing C++, Java, Scala and Go.
http://readwrite.com/2011/06/06/cpp-go-java-scala-performance-benchmark
The results in the table looked suspicious to me so I downloaded the code from https://code.google.com/p/multi-language-bench/source/checkout and ran the code myself. Strangely I got very different numbers. I didn't modify the code in any way. Just compiled and ran it.
According to google the run times(in seconds) are:

```
C++ - 23
Java 64bit - 134
Scala - 82
```

However on my machine I get

```
C++ - 13
Java - 14
Scala - 17
```

A much smaller difference in speed.
Now I wonder, is that simply because google improved the code of those benchmarks over the last year? Or maybe it has to do with improvements in the JVM?
btw. I use Java 1.7.0 64bit, Scala 2.10.0-RC2 and gcc 4.7.0 with -O2

Comment: Or maybe your particular machine has different properties than the machines they ran it on.

Comment: You probably want to add the scalac options for the target JVM and enable optimise. JDK7 includes improvements that Scala won't be taking advantage of [until 2.11](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/P_HDZNWETYk/V_Edgre8jkIJ). Its also worth remembering not to put too much faith in microbenchmarks, e.g. due to [unpredictable behavior](http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/1/1d/PerformanceAnxiety2010.pdf).